# How to change name of file if already present on remote machine?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to change the name of a file if it is already present on a remote server via SSH.

I tried this from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/685211/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-remote-server) (SuperUser)

```
bash
ssh user@localhost -p 2222 'test -f /absolute/path/to/file' && echo 'YES' || echo 'NO'
```

This works well with a prompt, echoes YES when the file exists and NO when it doesn't. But I want this to be launched from a crontab, then it must be in a script.

Let's assume the file is called `data.csv`, a condition is set in a loop such as if there already is a `data.csv` file on the server, the file will be renamed `data_1.csv` and then `data_2.csv`, ... until the name is unique.

The renaming part works, but the detection part doesn't :

```sh
while [[ $fileIsPresent!='false' ]]
do
    ((appended+=1))
    newFileName=${fileName}_${appended}.csv

    remoteFilePathname=${remoteFolder}${newFileName}

    ssh pi@localhost -p 2222 'test -f $remoteFilePathname' && fileIsPresent='true' || fileIsPresent='false'
done
```

always returns `fileIsPresent='true'` for any `data_X.csv`. All the paths are absolute.

Do you have any idea to help me?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus This tool is so powerful, thank you very much it helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$ cat replace.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$1" == "" ]]
then
    echo "No filename passed."
    exit
fi

if [[ ! -e "$1" ]]
then
    echo "no such file"
    exit
fi

base=${1%%.*} # get basename
ext=${1#*.} # get extension

for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
    new="${base}_${i}.${ext}"
    if [[ -e "$new" ]]
    then
        continue
    fi
    mv $1 $new
    exit
done

$ ./replace.sh sample.csv
no such file

$ touch sample.csv
$ ./replace.sh sample.csv 

$ ls
replace.sh
sample_1.csv

$ touch sample.csv
$ ./replace.sh sample.csv 

$ ls
replace.sh
sample_1.csv
sample_2.csv
```

However, personally I'd prefer to use a timestamp instead of a number. Note that this sample will run out of names after 100. Timestamps won't. Something like  `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)`.

Comment: Always quote your variables (so `mv $1 $new` should be `mv "$1" "$new"` (or even more robustly `mv -- "$1" "$new"`) and `$(seq 1 100)` can be just `{1..100}`.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for ideas to help you, I thought it worth mentioning that you probably don't want to start up to 100 `ssh` processes each one logging into the remote machine, so you might do better with a construct like this that only establishes a single `ssh` session that runs till complete:

```
ssh USER@REMOTE <<'EOF'
for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
  echo $i
done
EOF
```

---

Alternatively, you can create and test a `bash` script locally and then run it remotely like this:

```
ssh USER@REMOTE 'bash -s' < LocallyTestedScript.bash
```