# bash- awk get filename from pipe and use it to create another file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to get filename, rename it and then use it to create another file.

```
zcat input.gz | awk -F ',' '{if($3==1) {si = sprintf("%s1.gz", substr(FILENAME,length(FILENAME)-3)); print $1","$2","$3","$95","$100 | "gzip > ~/user/si"; }'
```

The created file has name `si` instead of the rename filename.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts here. Could you please also share sample of input and expected output in your question for clarity of question and let us know then.

Comment: Smells like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* are you tring to parse the filename?

Comment: Check out [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592276/how-to-change-name-of-file-if-already-present-on-remote-machine) I just shared. It does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$ awk -v filename=foo.gz '                   # set the filename to a var
BEGIN {
    incmd="zcat \047" filename "\047"        # fire zcat inside awk
    outcmd="gzip > \047../" filename "\047"  # redirect to gzip 
    while((incmd | getline )>0)              # read records
        print filename,$0 | outcmd           # filename in a var
}'
```

**Notice** that currently it writes to previous directory (..)/ to a file by the same name (`foo.gz`).

Comment: how can I avoid writing on previous directory?

Comment: Where would you like to write? You could define output filename with `-v` or `-v outpath=some_path` and `outcmd="gzip > \047" outpath "/" filename "\047"`

Comment: that doesn't work. It continues to write everything `../outpath` - @JamesBrown

Comment: @JamesBrown, ...this is not exactly a safe practice. What happens when instead of `foo.gz` you have `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.gz`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the file name within awk, just let the shell handle the output pipe and redirection:

```
file='input.gz'
zcat "$file" |
awk -F ',' -v OFS='","' '$3==1{print "\"" $1, $2, $3, $95, $100 "\""}' |
gzip > ~/user/"${file%.gz}1.gz"
```

I'm guessing at what the `$3==1` is for as I can't tell what it's for in your script since it's missing a closing `}` for the `if ... {` and I'm also assuming you want `"`s at the start and end of lines.

Comment: This answer works just fine but the above is more suitable to my problem, thank you @EdMorton